# How to pass the 'object' argument dynamically to anova() function

Tags: r, anova, lme4, nlme

I am struggling to write a script which allows for a more flexible approach to compare different linear mixed-effect models making use of the `lme4` or `nlme` package. As I do not want to adjust the script for each and every model I add or drop, I am looking for a **dynamic** approach. Doing so I would only have to adjust one variable which contains character strings of the model formulas.

This works fine unless `anova()` comes in. `anova()` does not accept a **list** of elements containing the appropriate classes:

```
###### Here is my problem
# comparing models by means of ANOVA
anova(lme.lst)                                  #### --> does not work
anova(lme.lst[[1]], lme.lst[[2]], lme.lst[[3]]) #### would work but kills the dynamic approach
######
```

I did not figure a neat way to decompose the list and pass multiple arguments to the `anova()` function. I tried `unlist()` without any success.

Here is a minimal example (adapted from [lme4 manual, p. 8](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/lme4.pdf)):

```
require(lme4)
require(AICcmodavg)

# Variable containing of strings in order to describe the fixed effect terms 
# (wihout response/dependen variable)                                            ### should be orderd from
callModel <- c("angle ~ recipe + temp        + (1|recipe:replicate)",  # model1  ### small
               "angle ~ recipe + temperature + (1|recipe:replicate)",  # model2  ### too                
               "angle ~ recipe * temperature + (1|recipe:replicate)")  # model3  ### BIG

# convert string array 'callFeVar' into a list of formulas
callModel <- sapply(callModel, as.formula)

# create an empty list for safing the results of fitted model 
lme.lst <- list()
# do model fitting in a loop and change list names
for (i in 1 : length(callModel)) {
  lmeTmp <- lmer(callModel[[i]], cake, REML= FALSE)
  lme.lst[i] <- list(lmeTmp)
  names(lme.lst)[i] <- deparse(callModel[[i]])
}
# remove temporary variable
rm(lmeTmp)

# summary of models
lapply(lme.lst, summary)

###### Here is my problem
# comparing models by means of ANOVA
anova(lme.lst)                                  #### --> does not work
anova(lme.lst[[1]], lme.lst[[2]], lme.lst[[3]]) #### would work but kills the dynamic approach
######

# comparing models by means of AICc
aictab(lme.lst)                                 #### accepts list
```

Answer (score 5):

`do.call` calls a function with arguments supplied in a list.

```
do.call(anova, lme.lst)
```

Comment: Does not work that way with the minimal example. I get:
`Error in anova.merMod(``angle ~ recipe + temp + (1 | recipe:replicate)`` = <S4 object of class "lmerMod">,  : 
  argument "object" is missing, with no default`

Comment: I just fiddled around a bit more figuring the following: When using `do.call`, `anova` does not like the list's name arguments. Therefore, wrapping the list in `unname` does the trick: `do.call(anova, unname(lme.lst))`.
Now it would be cool to also pass the `model.names` argument setting it to `names(me.lst)`. Any ideas? However, the latter would only be a "nice-to-have" feature.